# Will having "Muslim" stated on my passport cause issues at US immigration?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

I'm considering travelling to the United States next April. As a student of history and literature, I really want to see the historical sites in and around New England.

As someone with a Bahraini passport stating I am a Muslim, my only concern would be whether or not I will face any difficulties in immigration.

I don't look Muslim and I am not actually religious, but again my passport says "Muslim" on it. Just wondering if that will cause me any problems. If things go according to plan, I should arrive in Philadelphia in April 2018.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69714/discussion-on-question-by-nader-adnan-will-having-muslim-stated-on-my-passport).

Answer (score 27):

As long as your paper work is in order, it is highly unlikely that you will face any issues at immigration. Contact the US embassy in Bahrain for the exact requirements: https://bh.usembassy.gov/visas/nonimmigrant-visas/

Every day, over 5000 Muslim visitors enter the US and the vast majority have no issues whatsoever. See also https://www.crescentrating.com/magazine/travel-index-and-rankings/3809/six-stats-you-should-know-about-muslim-travel-to-the-usa.html

The immigration officer will inspect your paperwork and ask you a few questions ("why are you here", "what do you plan to do", "when will you go home", "where will you stay" "what's your profession", etc.) Just answer the questions truthfully and you will be fine. The amount of questioning is up to the immigration officer and can vary from a single grunt to a lengthy question and answer session. The later can happen regardless of your country of origin or your religion.

Answer (score 3):

No.  Provided your Visa and Passport are in order, you can expect an uneventful entry.  By uneventful, I mean little beyond the customary questions.

Note, while your Passport might say "Muslim", this is not part of the [Machine Readable Zone (MRZ)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-readable_passport) and is such not part of Passport information that is transmitted to CPB.  Additionally, the CBP Officers are 99.9% familiar with a Bahraini Passport so this will not be anything new or unusual.

Comment: Moreover, I am sure the vast majority of Bahraini passports are marked "Muslim".